# export more than 1 million records from dynamics-365-operations (AX 365)

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

hello we have the needs to export more than 1 million records from reports like detail trail balance report i there any way to exceed this standard limit
in oracle the export process divided to sets so we can export whatever number of records
is there in way in dynamics-365-operations AX to divid the export process to multiple times without need to do filter every time